# Duplicate file names in document library

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I want to prevent duplicate file names in a document library.

Let me know how can I enforce the unique names in the library.

Thanks
RH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an event receiver for the library on the ItemAdding, check if an item with that name already exist => if this is true add this code :

```
properties.Cancel = true;
properties.ErrorMessage = "Adding duplicate is not alowed.";
```

or use this : http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/301f3a11-498a-4cf7-93f1-774a032606d0

Comment: Your answer is correct but I have a more complicated scenario